# How can i clear view from navigation controller in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am creating navigation based iphone application.In that i have to move from one view to another view as the user selects, but in one point i want to move from 4th view to 2nd view 
I will explain you briefly
My Screens are
1) Menu
2) Event list of the selected menu (On this screen there is **navigation button on right on click of this button another view will open to select city when user selects the city it should go to second screen by clearing previously opened the same screen**)
3) same as above there is right button to change city.

So how can i do this in ios please help me.I done this in android by option called ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP i want that same in ios.

Comment: can you post code you tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

Comment: You question has changed such that it now seems you want to: A) choose a city in screen 3 which at the same time pops that view off the stack so that we are then back to screen two. B) In screen two you need to reload/refresh the data presented on that screen in viewWillAppear.